# htaccess - redirect GET parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a website which contains friendly URL's like localhost/article/xyz instead of localhost/article.php?name=xyz. It all works fine, but i discovered that I still can access the site also by typing "localhost/article.php?name=xyz". Is there a way to redirect it automatically to friendly URL?

```php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^article/([a-z,-]+)$ article.php?name=$1&
```

Just want to redirect that: "localhost/article.php?name=xyz" to "localhost/article/xyz".

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)$ article.php?q=$1 [QSA]`

For more information on how to use mod_rewrite check out the doc 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thank you, but I still can access the site by http://localhost/article.php?name=test, and it doesn't redirect me to http://localhost/article/test.